# Javascript/node.js Object that can store arbitrary binary data and do appending very fast

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I need to process lots of binary data in a Node.js app.  As data arrive in many small chunks (in the format of Buffer object) that comes to my part of code via a callback, I have to do MANY operations per second like appending, slicing etc.

I was tempted to store the binary data in Javascript string, which support appending, slicing etc. But unfortunately I can't really convert the (arbitrary) binary data to string, which has to have an valid encoding, like UTF8.

To use Buffer object, the appending operation become very expensive.  For example, the following code snippet took 1.5 seconds on my P7 processor.

```
var a = new Buffer([1])
var b = new Buffer([2])
var start = new Date()
for (i=0; i<100000; i++) {
a = Buffer.concat([a, b], a.length + 1)
}
console.log(new Date() - start)
```

If I were doing simple string appending `a += b` assuming a and b are strings, it will take only 0.01 second.

I wonder if there is an object in Javascript that can store arbitrary binary data and support appending very efficiently.

Thanks in advance

**Update1**

Tried TypeArray, the speed is a little better, but it's still far slower than string appending.

```
var a = new Uint8Array(),
    b = new Uint8Array(1);
var c
b[0] = 11
var start = new Date()
for (i=0; i<100000; i++) {
    c = new Uint8Array (a.length + b.length)
    c.set(a,0)
    c.set(b, a.length)
    a = c
}

console.log(new Date() - start)
console.log(a.length)
```

Comment: Did you look into TypedArrays?

Comment: No, let me check it out..

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel Tried it, but it still quite slow.

Comment: You can use arbitrary strings using `String.fromCharCode(number)` or what I am currently even doing is `String.fromCharCode(...TypedArray)` (... is the spread operator)

Comment: Here is what I read from document: `The static String.fromCharCode() method returns a string created from the specified sequence of UTF-16 code units.`  my binary data is arbitrary.

Comment: Every possible byte is a valid charcode. I wasn't sure but I tried `Array(100).fill(1).map(()=>Math.floor(Math.random()*2**8))` which results in no errors.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianSpeitel, I am still a little nervous with string here.  Going to adopt the solution by smart-buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`smart-buffer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smart-buffer) might be what you're after? It allows you to write other buffers into it and will dynamically resize as needed.

**Testing script:**

```
const SmartBuffer = require('smart-buffer').SmartBuffer;

// set up buffers
var a = new Buffer([1])
var smart_a = new SmartBuffer();
smart_a.writeInt8(1);

var b = new Buffer([2])

// time buffer concatenation method
console.time("Buffer concatenation");
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    a = Buffer.concat([a, b], a.length + 1)
}
console.timeEnd("Buffer concatenation");

// time smart buffer writeBuffer method
console.time("Smart Buffer writing");
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    smart_a.writeBuffer(b);
}
let final_smart_a = smart_a.toBuffer();
console.timeEnd("Smart Buffer writing");

// check that resulting buffers match
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    console.assert(a[i] == final_smart_a[i]);
}
```

**Results (1 trial):**

```
Buffer concatenation: 2110.282ms
Smart Buffer writing: 14.971ms
```

Comment: nice try @ollin-boer-bohan.  I would like to the performance to under 1 second doing 1,000,000 loops. Could you tweak it to do that?

Comment: The time taken by the smart buffer method for 1,000,000 loops is ~90ms on my machine. Performance will vary from computer to computer, but it should definitely be under a second regardless of what computer you're using. What are you asking me to tweak?

Comment: probably even a lot better if you specify the buffer size. The default size seems to be 4096

Comment: You are right @ollin-boer-bohan,  smart-buffer holds the promise.  Let me check if it's easy to convert Buffer object  into smart-buffer.  Thx

Comment: smart-buffer it is. Thanks @ollin-boer-bohan!